# The type 'foo.Info.AgentDetails' exists in both 'foo.dll' and 'foo.dll'

Tags: asp.net, dll

In my asp.net web application, one of my page, I am storing a list of objects(`List<AgentDetails>`) to ViewState. After that when I try to get it back as (`List<AgentDetails>)ViewState["ViewStateAgentDetails"]`, i gets an error like

> The type 'foo.Info.AgentDetails' exists in both 'foo.dll' and 'foo.dll'

I can't understand what is happening here.
I got stuck with this issue.
Could anybody help me out of this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remove all reference of `foo.dll` and then just add only one ref and clean, rebuild, it should work then.

Comment: @ArindamNayak Thanks for youe reply, Actually bin directoy have only one copy of the dll.

Answer (score 0):

If i interpret it correctly from answer to my comment, i can see that there might be some other DLL , that can have different dll name says `bar.dll`, but ultimately has same namespace and class name. So to fix this , find that second DLL, and use `extern` or change `namespace` to solve this error.

More explanation - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/abhinaba/archive/2005/11/30/498278.aspx

[How do you allow two DLL's with same namespace.class to exist in the same application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1172361/how-do-you-allow-two-dlls-with-same-namespace-class-to-exist-in-the-same-applic)